Linking libcurl on Windows Mingw32 returning Undefined References
I'm trying to link libcurl.a (I downloaded this from https://curl.se/windows/ for 32-bit Windows Machines and directly grabbed the static .a file). However, when I attempt to do so, I get the following error for undefined references.

This is my POST request code that uses libcurl:
void send_post_request(char* address, char* text, int text_size, char* exe_type, char* auth_key)
{
    // Initialize all sub modules because we're on Windows and might want HTTPS down the line
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    // Init a single thread $CURL "command instance" - or at least I like to think of it as a command instance because that's how it is on Kali
    CURL* curl_instance = curl_easy_init(); 

    // Set URL - address usually is a macro that is passed in by get_req.js at compile time
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_instance, CURLOPT_URL, address);

    // Set headers
    struct curl_slist* headers = NULL;

    char* to_send = malloc(5 + strlen(exe_type) + 1);       // EXE type  - Add 1 for null byte
    strcpy(to_send, "exe: ");
    strcat(to_send, exe_type);
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, to_send);

    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: text/plain");         // Content Type
    
    // Auth
    char* auth_send = malloc(15 + strlen(auth_key) + 1);
    strcpy(auth_send, "authorization: ");
    strcat(auth_send, auth_key);
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, auth_send);

    // Set headers
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_instance, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);

    // Set data to send
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_instance, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, text);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_instance, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, text_size);
    
    // Send the POST request
    curl_easy_perform(curl_instance);

    // Cleanup everything (and the POST request)
    free(to_send);
    free(auth_send);
    curl_slist_free_all(headers);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl_instance);
    curl_global_cleanup();
}

And here is my directory structure:
-- Libcurl --- libcurl.a
           --- All the curl header files

-- Post    --- post.c
           --- post.h
           --- post.o


First, I generated the object file (which returned no error and works perfectly fine).
gcc -c ./post.c -o post.o -I../Libcurl/ -I./

The error occurs in the Linking phase, which is where I get the error thrown.
gcc .\post.o -L../Libcurl/ -lcurl

Does anyone have any advice on how to fix this? I've tested everything else that was suggested on Stack Overflow, and it doesn't fix it. I feel like it might be a windows-specific issue or a newer version issue, but I'm not sure.
When I add -DCURL_STATICLIB flag, I get new undefined references:


Curl requires quite a few libraries to be linked in: nghttp2, zstd, zlib, openssl, etc.  If you are working within the msys2 environment, you can install curl and link with the msys2 curl libraries, which will have the correct dependencies (pkg-config --static --libs libcurl).   I build my own curl library as I only need the basics, and I don't have to ship so many unneeded libraries (it still links with zstd, zlib, openssl (and its dependencies), nghttp2 (which I also build), c-ares, and one or two more).  Shipping your own curl comes with its own set of problems (I ship the .dll files).

Don't post pictures of texts, post texts as texts in the question.
